# Mapping points to squares

Tags: algorithms, graph-traversal

I am working on writing a code for Hilbert algorithm to solve a [Traveling Salesmen Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). Although there are several efficient methods out there, I am just curious about the implementation of [Hilbert Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) filling curve.

[image]

1. First we create a Hilbert curve and divide the entire area into a number of squares.
2. Then using the sequence of squares we connect all the points though which the salesmen has to travel.

My problem is on the second part. How can I find the squares which contains a point? Or how can I find the empty squares?

Comment: I imagine the details of how to do this may depend on your data structures: how are you representing the points and squares in your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *find the squares which contains a point*,  the search domain, i.e. a collection of points, conceptually must contain retrievable attributes, such as number of points, whether a point is to be visited, and even the order in which a point will be visited.  An array of a simple struct comes to mind as one implementation that could be used to model such a domain.

in C for example:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;  //x position in domain
    int y;  //y position in domain
}P; //point

typedef struct {
    P p;
    BOOL occupied; //1 = will be visited, 0 = will NOT be visited
    int sequence;  //0 if not visited, 1-n indicated order of visit.
}DOMAIN;  // example points: {{0, 0}, 1, 1}, {{0, 1}, 0, 0} 
          // meaning:      The point at position 0,0 will be visited first
          //               The point at position 0,1 will not be visited.

//Model of some existing domain using the DOMAIN struct.   
//This one is comprised of 25 points, arranged in 5x5 square,     
//but if a domain of different dimensions is required, (and can   
//be represented in this fashion) modify these initializers to   
//meet those needs:  

DOMAIN domain[] = {{{0,0},1,1},{{0,1},0,-1},{{0,2},0,-1},{{0,3},0,-1},{{0,4},0,-1},
                   {{1,0},0,-1},{{1,1},0,-1},{{1,2},0,-1},{{1,3},0,-1},{{1,4},0,-1},
                   {{2,0},0,-1},{{2,1},1,2},{{2,2},0,-1},{{2,3},0,-1},{{2,4},0,-1},
                   {{3,0},0,-1},{{3,1},0,-1},{{3,2},0,-1},{{3,3},1,3},{{3,4},0,-1},
                   {{4,0},0,-1},{{4,1},1,4},{{4,2},0,-1},{{4,3},0,-1},{{4,4},1,5} };


int main(void)
{   //Get the total number of points existing in domain:
    int pointCount = sizeof(domain)/sizeof(domain[0]);
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<pointCount;i++)
    {   //determine point by point which are to be occupied...
        if(domain[i].occupied == TRUE)
        {   //For any point to be occupied, indicate its location
            //and in what order (sequence) it will be occupied.  
            printf("point[%d,%d] is occupied with sequence %d\n", domain[i].p.x,domain[i].p.y, domain[i].sequence);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The results of this domain, with points that will be occupied, and the order of occupation:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I have got any idea after seeing your code and i will try to implement it Python. :)